# dotnet build failing inside container

Tags: .net, .net-core, containers, rhel, dotnet-build

I encountered a really annoying issue when trying to execute dotnet builds within a container for a standard CI/CD flow. The issues seem to occur 'randomly' (on average about 4/10 builds fail when ran from Jenkins without any changes made to the code or config in between).
The issues I'm getting (It seems a bit random which one occurs when - stacktrace below):

1. MSB4018: CreateAppHost task failed unexpectedly - occurs most frequently

```
/opt/rh/rh-dotnet31/root/usr/lib64/dotnet/sdk/3.1.103/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/targets/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.targets(393,5): error MSB4018: The "CreateAppHost" task failed unexpectedly. [/opt/app-root/<project_path>/<project_csproj>]
/opt/rh/rh-dotnet31/root/usr/lib64/dotnet/sdk/3.1.103/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/targets/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.targets(393,5): error MSB4018: System.IO.IOException: The process cannot access the file '/opt/app-root/<project_path>/Pse.Spr.Reports.Web/obj/Release/netcoreapp3.1/Pse.Spr.Reports.Web' because it is being used by another process. [/opt/app-root/<project_path>/<project_csproj>]
/opt/rh/rh-dotnet31/root/usr/lib64/dotnet/sdk/3.1.103/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/targets/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.targets(393,5): error MSB4018:    at System.IO.FileStream.Init(FileMode mode, FileShare share, String originalPath) in /_/src/System.Private.CoreLib/shared/System/IO/FileStream.Unix.cs:line 120 [/opt/app-root/<project_path>/<project_csproj>]
/opt/rh/rh-dotnet31/root/usr/lib64/dotnet/sdk/3.1.103/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/targets/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.targets(393,5): error MSB4018:    at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options) in /_/src/System.Private.CoreLib/shared/System/IO/FileStream.cs:line 252 [/opt/app-root/<project_path>/<project_csproj>]
/opt/rh/rh-dotnet31/root/usr/lib64/dotnet/sdk/3.1.103/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/targets/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.targets(393,5): error MSB4018:    at System.IO.FileSystem.CopyFile(String sourceFullPath, String destFullPath, Boolean overwrite) in /_/src/System.IO.FileSystem/src/System/IO/FileSystem.Unix.cs:line 29 [/opt/app-root/<project_path>/<project_csproj>]
/opt/rh/rh-dotnet31/root/usr/lib64/dotnet/sdk/3.1.103/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/targets/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.targets(393,5): error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.NET.HostModel.AppHost.BinaryUtils.CopyFile(String sourcePath, String destinationPath) [/opt/app-root/<project_path>/<project_csproj>]
/opt/rh/rh-dotnet31/root/usr/lib64/dotnet/sdk/3.1.103/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/targets/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.targets(393,5): error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.NET.HostModel.AppHost.HostWriter.CreateAppHost(String appHostSourceFilePath, String appHostDestinationFilePath, String appBinaryFilePath, Boolean windowsGraphicalUserInterface, String assemblyToCopyResorcesFrom) [/opt/app-root/<project_path>/<project_csproj>]
/opt/rh/rh-dotnet31/root/usr/lib64/dotnet/sdk/3.1.103/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/targets/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.targets(393,5): error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.NET.Build.Tasks.CreateAppHost.ExecuteCore() [/opt/app-root/<project_path>/<project_csproj>]
/opt/rh/rh-dotnet31/root/usr/lib64/dotnet/sdk/3.1.103/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/targets/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.targets(393,5): error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.NET.Build.Tasks.TaskBase.Execute() [/opt/app-root/<project_path>/<project_csproj>]
/opt/rh/rh-dotnet31/root/usr/lib64/dotnet/sdk/3.1.103/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/targets/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.targets(393,5): error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute() [/opt/app-root/<project_path>/<project_csproj>]
/opt/rh/rh-dotnet31/root/usr/lib64/dotnet/sdk/3.1.103/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/targets/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.targets(393,5): error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.ExecuteInstantiatedTask(ITaskExecutionHost taskExecutionHost, TaskLoggingContext taskLoggingContext, TaskHost taskHost, ItemBucket bucket, TaskExecutionMode howToExecuteTask) [/opt/app-root/<project_path>/<project_csproj>]
```

2. MSB4018: GenerateDepsFile task failed unexpectedly

```
/opt/rh/rh-dotnet31/root/usr/lib64/dotnet/sdk/3.1.103/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/targets/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.targets(192,5): error MSB4018: The "GenerateDepsFile" task failed unexpectedly. [/opt/app-root/<project_path>/<project_csproj>]
/opt/rh/rh-dotnet31/root/usr/lib64/dotnet/sdk/3.1.103/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/targets/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.targets(192,5): error MSB4018: System.IO.IOException: The process cannot access the file '/opt/app-root/<project_release_path><*.deps.json>' because it is being used by another process. [/opt/app-root/<project_path>/<project_csproj>]
/opt/rh/rh-dotnet31/root/usr/lib64/dotnet/sdk/3.1.103/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/targets/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.targets(192,5): error MSB4018:    at System.IO.FileStream.Init(FileMode mode, FileShare share, String originalPath) in /_/src/System.Private.CoreLib/shared/System/IO/FileStream.Unix.cs:line 120 [/opt/app-root/<project_path>/<project_csproj>]
/opt/rh/rh-dotnet31/root/usr/lib64/dotnet/sdk/3.1.103/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/targets/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.targets(192,5): error MSB4018:    at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options) in /_/src/System.Private.CoreLib/shared/System/IO/FileStream.cs:line 252 [/opt/app-root/<project_path>/<project_csproj>]
/opt/rh/rh-dotnet31/root/usr/lib64/dotnet/sdk/3.1.103/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/targets/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.targets(192,5): error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.NET.Build.Tasks.GenerateDepsFile.WriteDepsFile(String depsFilePath) [/opt/app-root/<project_path>/<project_csproj>]
/opt/rh/rh-dotnet31/root/usr/lib64/dotnet/sdk/3.1.103/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/targets/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.targets(192,5): error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.NET.Build.Tasks.TaskBase.Execute() [/opt/app-root/<project_path>/<project_csproj>]
/opt/rh/rh-dotnet31/root/usr/lib64/dotnet/sdk/3.1.103/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/targets/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.targets(192,5): error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute() [/opt/app-root/<project_path>/<project_csproj>]
/opt/rh/rh-dotnet31/root/usr/lib64/dotnet/sdk/3.1.103/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/targets/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.targets(192,5): error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.ExecuteInstantiatedTask(ITaskExecutionHost taskExecutionHost, TaskLoggingContext taskLoggingContext, TaskHost taskHost, ItemBucket bucket, TaskExecutionMode howToExecuteTask)
```

3. NETSDK1029: Unable to use .../apphost as application host executable as it does not contain the expected placeholder byte sequence - my personal favorite :)

```
/usr/lib64/dotnet/sdk/3.1.117/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/targets/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.targets(393,5): error NETSDK1029: Unable to use '/usr/lib64/dotnet/packs/Microsoft.NETCore.App.Host.rhel.8-x64/3.1.17/runtimes/rhel.8-x64/native/apphost' as application host executable as it does not contain the expected placeholder byte sequence '63-33-61-62-38-66-66-31-33-37-32-30-65-38-61-64-39-30-34-37-64-64-33-39-34-36-36-62-33-63-38-39-37-34-65-35-39-32-63-32-66-61-33-38-33-64-34-61-33-39-36-30-37-31-34-63-61-65-66-30-63-34-66-32' that would mark where the application name would be written. [/opt/app-root/<project_csproj>]
```

About now I think I've gone through all of the search results and none of the answers has helped so far - so maybe here I'll get lucky (and hopefully help someone in the process).

### Technical data:

**Jenkins agent** 
Running on RHEL 8.4 with Podman v. 3.2.3

**Container data** 
OS - RHEL7.9 and RHEL8.4 (I tried both)
Is run with a mounted volume from the Jenkins agent (the directory with the source code from cloned from the repository).
Basic Dockerfile setup where I use a RHEL8 base image from our internal repository - the RHEL7 is a modified by installing scl-utils and such but the general idea is the same

```
ARG rhel_version=7.9
ARG build_version=1.0.0
 
FROM <baseRHELimage>
 
ENV HOME=/opt/app-root/ \
    DOTNET_APP_PATH=/opt/app-root/
    #DOTNET_RUNNING_IN_CONTAINER=true
 
# Don't download/extract docs for nuget packages
ENV NUGET_XMLDOC_MODE=skip
 
RUN <setup yum repos>
    dnf install -y dotnet-sdk-3.1 &&\
    dnf update -y; dnf clean all
```

**.NET data** 
Using dotnet core 3.1 SDK

The issues occur when I try to run a dotnet build.
The Jenkinsfile is firstly removing all bin/ and obj/ directories in the first stage and then invoking the build for the application.

### The most promising things I tried:

- Some people suggested that the folders bin/ and obj/ needed to be fully deleted - this is happening in the first stage prior to the run
- I tried splitting up the dotnet publish command into:

```
    dotnet restore 
    dotnet build --no-restore
    dotnet publish --no-build
```

... keeps throwing one of those 3 errors randomly across builds directly withing **dotnet build**

I tried invoking that dotnet build with different flags like 'no-parallel' thinking maybe threads are somehow the root cause (I am getting a lot of 'process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process' warnings - but these happen for the successful builds as well - the default dotnet retries seem to be handling those

Anyone any idea what I might be missing? The CI/CD pipeline was running previously on a RHEL7.7 agent directly (no containers used).
Now we want to move to containerized builds with newer versions of RedHat - but these randomly reoccuring issues are blocking me so if anyone has any suggestions - greatly appreciated ;)

Comment: Maybe something is building in parallel and two projects tries build same dependent project?
Multi-target projects can have same "parallel" issue.

Comment: @LukaszSzczygielek - shouldn't the 'no-parallel' flag for the dotnet build handle that? I tried to look through the project and some projects have shared dependencies to a common library. This dll is built first so it shouldn't pose that many problems. And since some of the builds succeed I'd like to avoid making changes to the project since that requires engaging a whole other team and so on (complicated company infrastructure) - if possible I'd like to get the issue resolved using only CI/CD tools

Comment: This sounds like it could be a bug somewhere. Could you file an issue in our tracker? We can try and work though this: https://github.com/redhat-developer/s2i-dotnetcore

Comment: Are you volume mounting your code into the container? Could it be that multiple processes or multiple containers are trying to build the same set of files on disk, leading to concurrency issues?

Comment: @omajid I filed an issue in the  tracker. As for the processes - we're still in POC phase for the containerized builds so I'm using a separate jenkins-agent machine with only one running container so there shouldn't be any access to the mounted volume from other processes